# How can I change the key bindings in VS Code to change the tab key to four spaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running the latest version of VS Code and Windows 10.  I'm learning Python and would like all of my indentations to be spaces.  However, I'd like to use the tab key to enter those spaces.

I've tried many different variations in the keybindings.json file with no luck.

```
[
    {
        "key": "tab", 
        "command": "-tab"
    },

    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "type",
        "args": {"text": "       "}
    }
]
```

With the above code, I was just trying out many spaces to check the difference.  However, when I save this as the json file, it doesn't give expected behavior.  It will indent the full amount, but when I backspace I'd expect it to go back one space.  Yet, it backs up to where a standard tab would be..  hitting it again returns to the beginning of the line.

Is it possible for the tab key to simply be used as a macro for four spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change it in json files. You can search `Tab Size` in VSCode Settings and change its value to 4. If this does not work, click the `Editor: Detect Indentation` link and disable it. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I tried both of these again and it's still not working as I hoped.  It still inserts a tab instead of spaces.  The `Editor: Insert Spaces` is checked.

Comment: When you hit the `Tab` key, the editor should insert four spaces by default, and `backspace` will remove four spaces at one time, which may cause you to think it's a tab. You can try to hit `Tab` and see if it inserts four spaces by pressing `←` and `→`.

Comment: I guess my end issue is that when I copy and paste code to a website, it's still formatting them as tabs.

Comment: Try to paste the code to a txt file, and if that's four spaces, then it's the website's fault.